# List comparison with keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to think of the best way to solve this issue.

I basically want to grab some text, and compare it against a keyword.

Of course, I could do:

```
keyword = 'python 3.5'
title = 'python 3.5 is a programming language'
if keyword in title:
```

However, it has to be in that order. If the title text happened to be:

```
title = 'my favourite version of python is 3.5!'
```

That would not work.

So, I have tried coming up with a way of splitting the the keyword with `.split()` and then checking if both items from the split keyword list are in the title variable, but have had no luck coming up with an efficient way.

If anyone knows a good way to do so, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: How granular you want that to be ? Word based? i.e., you want to search if contains("python") && contains("3.5") in order ? Or if keyword was "py 3.5" the above strings would also be valid ?

Comment: Also in that order that you say is that python has to be before 3.5 ?

Comment: @holandaGo I basically want to have a single keyword and search hundreds of strings for said keyword. As long as the string I am searching contains, from the given example, 'python' AND '3.5' it'd return a match, no matter the order.

Comment: Then it's a no brainer, just split the keyword in words and check if all are contained

Comment: @holandaGo of course, I stated this is what I needed doing in my initial question. It was just finding an efficient way of doing so, which thanks to the 6 kind people below I now have.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
keyword = 'python 3.5'
title = 'python 3.5 is a programming language'
s=set(keyword.split(" "))
m=set(title.split(" "))
if(len(set.intersection(s,m)==len(s)): 
   print(True)
```

Assuming that you don't care about repetitions. That is, that you consider

```
keyword = 'python 3.5 python'
title = 'python 3.5 is a programming language'
```

To be a pair in which all the keyword is indeed inside the title.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to find each word of the key phrase, in order, in the title.  Try this: search for each word in order; resume the search in the remainder of the title.

```
key_phrase = 'python 3.5'
title_list = ['python 3.5 is a programming language',
              'my favourite version of python is 3.5!']

key_word = key_phrase.split()

for title in title_list:
    remain = title.split()
    found = True
    for word in key_word:
        if word in remain:
            pos = remain.index(word)
            remain = remain[pos+1:]
        else:
            found = False

    print title, "\tfound=", found
```

Output:

```
python 3.5 is a programming language    found= True
my favourite version of python is 3.5!  found= False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...if you want to customize the precision of match cases.

```
keyword = 'python 3.5'
title = 'my favourite version of python is 3.5!'
precision = 100 # 100% precision (both python and 3.5 must exist in title)
if len([x for x in set(keyword.split(' ')) if x in title]) >= round(len(set(keyword.split(' ')))*(precision/100)):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

output:

```
'Yes'
```

if you change `title` to this:

```
title = 'my favourite version of python is 3.4!'
```

output will be `'No'`
But...with some modification of `precision`:

```
precision = 50
```

output will be `'Yes'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `all()`

```
title = 'my favourite version of python is 3.5!'

keyword = 'python 3.5'
print all(n in title for n in keyword.split())

keyword = 'hello 3.5'
print all(n in title for n in keyword.split())

keyword = 'hello world'
print all(n in title for n in keyword.split())

keyword = 'python 2.0'
print all(n in title for n in keyword.split())
```

results in

```
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Short *one-liner* using built-in [***any()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [***str.split()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) functions:

```
keyword = 'python 3.5'
title = 'my favourite version of python is 3.5!'

print(all(i in title for i in keyword.split()))
```

The output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to compare lists (it's slow), you should compare sets. As a bonus, `issubset` is already defined :

```
title = 'python 3.5 is a programming language'

def contains_all_keywords(sentence, keywords):
  keywords = set(keywords.split())
  return(keywords.issubset(set(sentence.split())))

print(contains_all_keywords(title, 'python 3.5'))
# True
print(contains_all_keywords(title, '3.5 python'))
# True
print(contains_all_keywords(title, 'python 2.7'))
# False
```